# Drupal 7 node custom template or core display

Tags: php, templates, drupal-7, nodes

I have dozens content types in which I need to display more or less block of the same fields. Using core display I have to create many groups and even than styling them with css is tricky.
My alternative is to use template suggestions but will they render faster than normal display method I'm currently using?
It will be easier to remove thoose fields from display, write the templates and render node in template (all the other data).
But how about performance?

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer is not so specific I would say that **printing what you need in tpl.php files is faster than hidding them with css or php if conditions**. So you should better use tpl.php files for each node type. And "core method" you are talking about is using tpl.php files! Look inside ROOT/modules/node folder for the tpl files of node module.

There are also some useful modules to help you with that like [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds), [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), [entity_view_modes](http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) etc but if performance is a big issue you can go without them.